# Subversion connection with C # in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, svn, visual-studio-2010, sharpsvn

**I am using to connect the library with subversion Sharpsvn but I always get an error.
The code is as follows:**

```
SvnClient client = new SvnClient();

string targetSource = "http://xxxxxxx/svn/xxxx/xxxx/";

string uriDest = "C:/Documents and Settings/user/My documents/Jesus/project/test";

client.CheckOut(new Uri(targetSource), uriDest, SvnRevision.Head.Revision, true);
```

**Although lack of authentication, if I try to run this code I get the following error in the Main () of the project:**

"The mixed-mode assembly was compiled with version 'v2.0.50727' runtime and can not be loaded at runtime 4.0 without additional configuration information."

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your config file:

```
<configuration>
   <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
       <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
   </startup>
</configuration>
```

It seems that the used library is not built to target the .NET 4.0 runtime.

Comment: Thank you very much! I now work correctly.

I've proven to do a checkout and entirely correct. What I would like to know is how to determine the size of the download directory is to show the process in a progressbar